# Sort array based on presence of fields in objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

How can I sort array something like below if any of fields is missing?

So existing array for example is:

```
const users = [
    {
        id: 1, firstname: 'Jerry'
    }, {
        id: 2, firstname: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Geib'
    }, {
        id: 3
    }, {
        id: 4, lastname: 'Berg'
    }, {
        id: 5, firstname: 'Ass', lastname: 'Noob'
    }, {
        id: 6, lastname: 'Jopa'
    }
]
```

and the result should be sorted in this order:

1. Object with `firstname` and `lastname`
2. Object only with `firstname` or `lastname`
3. Object without `firstname` and `lastname`

so that it would look like:

```
    const users = [
        {
            id: 2, firstname: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Geib'
        }, {
            id: 5, firstname: 'Ass', lastname: 'Noob'
        }, {
            id: 1, firstname: 'Jerry'
        }, {
            id: 4, lastname: 'Berg'
        }, {
            id: 6, lastname: 'Jopa'
        }, {
            id: 3
        }
    ]
```

I've tried this sorting but result is not that I needed

```
users.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.firstname === b.firstname) {
        return 0
    }
    if (!a.firstname) {
        return 1
    }
    return -1
});
```

Comment: what are you sorting your object based off?

Comment: lastname i guess

Comment: I suppose that the least number of object fields value to be the last one in array

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't text that. I edited question

Comment: You are not checking the actual values

Comment: @hofshteyn your edit still doesn't clarify what should happen if 2 users have both `firstname` and `lastname`?

Comment: The question I have is what is the expected order after it is sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just count the number of properties each item has and sort by this number, descending:

```js
var users = [
  {id: 1,firstname: 'Jerry'}, 
  {id: 2,firstname: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Geib'}, 
  {id: 3}, 
  {id: 4,lastname: 'Berg'}, 
  {id: 5,firstname: 'Ass',lastname: 'Noob'}, 
  {id: 6,lastname: 'Jopa'}
];
users.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aw = ('firstname' in a) + ('lastname' in a);
  var bw = ('firstname' in b) + ('lastname' in b);
  return bw - aw;
});
console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could sort by the check if the property exists. At the end sort by `id` ascending.

```js
const users = [{ id: 1, firstname: 'Jerry' }, { id: 2, firstname: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Geib' }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4, lastname: 'Berg' }, { id: 5, firstname: 'Ass', lastname: 'Noob' }, { id: 6, lastname: 'Jopa' }];

users.sort((a, b) => 
    ('firstname' in b && 'lastname' in b ) - ('firstname' in a && 'lastname' in a) ||
    ('firstname' in b) - ('firstname' in a) ||
    ('lastname' in b) - ('lastname' in a) ||
    a.id - b.id
);

console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```